# Cannot remove item in list

Tags: python

**i want remove list with input but i got error**

```
menu = {
    "isi" : ["butter","jagung"],
    "harga" : [1000,2000]
}

hapus = input("insert name want to delete ->  ")
menu.get("isi").remove(hapus)
menu.get("harga").remove(hapus)
```

This is my data here. I want to delete using an avalanche like the code below, but if I input butter  `ValueError: list. remove: x not in list` even butter is on the list

Comment: What do you expect the last line to do?

Comment: only want to print(menu)

Answer (score 0):

If you enter "butter", the second `remove` will cause the `ValueError`, given that it is not in the list `[1000, 2000]`. You need to check for existence of the item before removing.

You can achieve it like this:

```
def remove_item(l, item):
    if item in l:
        l.remove(item)

menu = {
    "isi" : ["butter","jagung"],
    "harga" : [1000,2000]
}

hapus = input("insert name want to delete ->  ")
remove_item(menu.get("isi"), hapus) 
remove_item(menu.get("harga"), hapus)

print(menu)
```

**FOLLOW UP**: if, as suggested in comments, what you want is to delete the items of in the other lists in the position corresponding to "butter", you could use the following approach (this will allow you to manage multiple occurrences of the entered item, and many entries in the `menu` dictionary):

```
def remove_item(menu, item):
    l1 = menu.get("isi")
    indeces = [i for i, v in enumerate(l1) if v == item]
    for i in indeces:
        for k in menu.keys():
            menu.get(k).pop(i)

menu = {
    "isi" : ["butter","jagung"],
    "harga" : [1000,2000]
}

hapus = input("insert name want to delete ->  ")

remove_item(menu, hapus)

print(menu)
```

Comment: The OP is expecting to remove value from the second list as well, probably the matching index to the value from the first list (he/she need to tell what exactly they are trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you wish is to remove the corresponding value in the second list according to the first one.

As for `butter` input:

```
menu = {
    "isi" : ["butter","jagung"],
    "harga" : [1000,2000]
}

hapus = input("insert name want to delete ->  ")
index_for_second_list = menu.get("isi").index(hapus)
menu.get("isi").remove(hapus)
menu.get("harga").pop(index_for_second_list)
print(menu)
```

Output:

```
{'isi': ['jagung'], 'harga': [2000]}
```